# Winforms DLL does not start under DCOM

Tags: c++, winforms, dcom, opc

I have my own OPC server based on ATL(exe module). User interface based on WinForms(DLL module). In the `_tWinMain` in the separate thread I call `Application::Run()` from DLL. This works fine if I launch my server manually or if the server launched by local OPC client. However, OPC client is located on other machine and if I try to start the server, the server starts successfully, but UI Window is not displayed.

Any ideas??
Thanks

Comment: UPD: The user interactive mode was not applied because, HKCR\CLSID\{ID}\AppID = {ID} key was missing. Now this works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your server DCOM settings:

[image: DCOM settings]

Most likely server is configured to run as a launching user, so it is executed on the separate Window Station and GUI is not visible for the logged on user. If you change config to use the interactive user, a problem should be solved. Although if no user is currently logged on, your server will be unable to start.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very likely this is the right direction to solve my problem. But this changes do not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behavior. One solution to modify your exe to look for a running instance and try to display the UI.

Example (put this in ::InitInstance)

```
HWND hWnd = ::FindWindowEx(NULL, NULL, NULL, [Your title]);
if (hWnd)
{
    ::ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    ::SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
    return FALSE;
}
```

Now when your server launched by a remote client, you can simply try to launch the server exe on the server machine, and it displays the UI.

Maybe the above won't work for you with some tweak (an ATL opc server with WinForm ui a little bit strange for me, MFC may be a better /but pain/ for this).

The only drawback that the OPC server must be launched with the currently logged in user security principal. Otherwise the UI won't be displayed (ShowWindow will have no effect)